# Undefined references to "__gx_personality_sj0" and others when trying to include boost::thead in project

Tags: c++, boost, g++

I've recently been trying to make use of the boost libraries and whilst I have been able to include header-only libraries just fine I'm now stuck on including the linked libraries. I've managed to use b2 to build the libraries with gcc and then link to them, but whilst trying to include thread I get [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktq0y.png) errors.

I've read that these errors can be caused by using the wrong toolset for building but I can't see how I could of got that wrong as I've only ever used mingw and I used toolset=gcc when building. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwnUf.png) are my toolchain executables just in case I have done something wrong there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shall submit exact compilation line that produces such errors. Make sure, that you are using g++, not gcc, but problem may be also in linking order.

Comment: mingw offers various "flavours" of tooling and runtime, w.r.t. the error, the exception throwing/handler mechanism as well. If there is a mismatch between the tool(s) used and the runtime, you can get errors like this.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov I've tried swapping the linking order between boost::thread and boost::system but this produces the same errors. As for the compilation line I'm using code::blocks, so how would I get this?

Comment: @Niall How would I solve this then? Is there a way to make the boost building tool use the 'correct' variation when executed?

Comment: IIRC, it will use the environment g++ it finds, so I imagine it is something wrong/inconsistent in the environment. One technique here is to create a "clean" shell environment and slowly add to it (i.e. tool paths etc.) until it works (or the error occurs) and then you will find out what the root cause is.

Comment: @Niall So if I understand correctly (this is pretty much my first experience with using the command line) I have to edit PATH such that it contains the directory of the version of g++ I am using? At the moment it seems to contain the directory of mingw used by Haskell, but when I try to change my toolchain in code blocks to use these files instead I get even more errors. Have I misunderstood anything or is this normal?

Comment: Yes, I would edit the path to point to the g++ you want to use (not the haskell one). You can control these things in CodeBlocks (I just don't remember how off hand). I would have boost and the CodeBlocks use the non-Haskell toolchain (it may be too old to handle the code you have).

Comment: @Niall I'm not using the Haskell toolchain in code blocks ( I just did that as a test) and I'm fairly sure the mingw version I'm using on code blocks is appropriate as I have managed to get opengl and the header-only boost libraries to work on it. I'll give changing the windows path variable to the correct directory then rebuilding a shot and see if that works.

Comment: @Nesou2, This is done by selecting the "Full command line" option Under menu "Settings" -> "Compiler" -> Global compiler settings -> [the compiler you use] -> "Other Setting" tab, "Compiler logging".

Comment: @Niall Removing Haskell from the path variable and adding the version of mingw that I was using then re-compiling the libraries fixes it. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov I've managed to fix the problem ;turns out I was building the libraries with the wrong version of mingw due to path variable being incorrect. Thanks though, I'll make sure I post the full command line next time I have a problem like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my path variable was incorrect and included Haskells mingw directory instead of the one I was using. After getting rid of Haskell from my path and adding the directy of the version mingw that I was using everything worked as intended.